# finding basis for sub-vector of R[x]

Tags: linear-algebra

i have a Span with 3 groups of polynomials(R4[x) (am i expressing myself correctly?) Sp{P1(x),P2(x),P3(x)}
it doesn't matter what the polynomials are, i just need to know how to find basis for the Span

is it the same as with numbers? Put them in a matrix and use gaussian elimination?
for example:

\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2x & 3x^2\\
2 & x & 7x^2\\
5 & 3x & 10x^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
Row3-->Row3-row1-row2.

which means Row 1 and 2 are basis for the span?

or with polynomials it's different?

Comment: I have typeset you matrix in $\LaTeX$, please check whether it is what you intended.

Comment: yes, thank you!

Comment: And then, as in the general case of vectors, you might write in the matrix only the coefficients, not also the *vectors* $x$, $x^2$.

Comment: isn't it important to note in the matrix that x and x^2 are dependant?

Answer (score 1):

You do not put the terms in the matrix as you have done.

Suppose you are given $p_1(x) = 3x^2 + 2x + 3$, $p_2(x) = 7x^2 + x + 2$, and $p_3(x) = 10x^2 + 3x + 5$ in $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$, the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most two. Suppose now that you wish to find the span of $\{p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x)\}$, and a basis for that span. Clearly $\{p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x)\}$ is a spanning set, but it may not be linearly independent, so we must check to see whether there are any non-trivial solutions to the equation $$c_1p_1(x) + c_2p_2(x) + c_3p_3(x) = 0.$$

Substituting in the expressions for the polynomials we obtain

\begin{align*}
c_1(3x^2 + 2x + 3) + c_2(7x^2+x+2) + c_3(10x^2+3x+5) &= 0\\
(3c_1 + 7c_2 + 10c_3)x^2 + (2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3)x + (3x_1 + 2c_2 + 5c_3) &= 0.
\end{align*}

As two polynomials are equal if and only if the corresponding coefficients are equal, we have

\begin{align*}
3c_1 + 7c_2 + 10c_3 &= 0\\
2c_1 + c_2 + 3c_3 &= 0\\
3x_1 + 2c_2 + 5c_3 &= 0
\end{align*}

which can of course be written in the matrix form:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
3 & 7 & 10\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
3 & 2 & 5
\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3
\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix}\right].$$

So the question about finding the span of a collection of polynomials reduces to some basic linear algebra (which hopefully you know how to do).

---

It is not immediately clear how one would approach the same problem for a collection of vectors in a different vector space; it seems that we used the polynomial structure in an essential way. In fact, we can do the exact same thing in any vector space, we just need to use the correct interpretation of what we did above.

The vector space $\mathbb{R}_2[x]$ has a natural ordered basis, $\mathcal{B} = \{x^2, x, 1\}$. Note that $p_1(x) = 3x^2 + 2x + 3$ expresses $p_1(x)$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors. The coefficients in this linear combination form what we call the coordinates of $p_1(x)$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$. We write them as follows:

$$[p_1(x)]_{\mathcal{B}} = \left[\begin{matrix}3\\ 2\\ 3\end{matrix}\right].$$

Note that this is precisely the first column of the matrix above. The coordinates of $p_2(x)$ and $p_3(x)$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ are the second and third columns respectively. Note, this process allows us to take a collection of vectors in any finite-dimensional vector space and convert them into a collection of vectors in Euclidean space, all we need to do is choose a basis. Furthermore, linearly independent sets are preserved by this correspondence. To be precise, we have the following:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with chosen ordered basis $\mathcal{B}$, and let $v_1, \dots, v_k \in V$. The set $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ is linearly independent $\Leftrightarrow$ $\{[v_1]_{\mathcal{B}}, \dots, [v_k]_{\mathcal{B}}\}$ is linearly independent.

So we can reduce questions about linear independence in any finite-dimensional vector space to the corresponding question in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where we can use the standard techniques of linear algebra.